# WSDL without endpoint URL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

Can a WSDL exist without an Endpoint defined in it? I received an WSDL from client which dont have have endpoint defined.

Just want to know what are the possibilities if it exist somewhere else or in some other relative location etc since I don't have expertise in SOAP services.

To make clear further the WSDL dont have `soap:address` neither `service` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sure can. The same WSDL can be defined for multiple endpoints. You need to ask the client which address(es) to use with that.

Comment: Thank you. I will ask. But since you are saying that "same WSDL can be defined for multiple endpoints" but I cant see the endpoint. How and where to define these endpoints? If you can guide me to some resource from I can get an understanding/defining the multiple endpoints out of the wsdl for that wsdl.

Comment: @Garry I meant rather addresses than endpoints. The WSDL defines the paths and other such things, but doesn't need to care where the final product is actually deployed to.

Comment: So you mean to say that wherever the WSDL will be deployed the location of WSDL will be becomes its endpoint?

Comment: @Garry No, the WSDL and endpoint have (practically) nothing to do with each other. WSDL defines the format of the service, it doesn't need to care where you deploy it. WSDL defines the service, it can define endpoints, but it certainly doesn't need to.

Comment: OK, as I understand. Endpoint is optional for WSDL. If a WSDL is without endpoint then it can accessed by the location where the WSDL is deployed. Correct? If this is correct what is the significance of endpoint? Why the concept of endpoint is exist if WSDL can exist without it?

Comment: I can send you a WSDL without giving you an endpoint. You can't do anything with it since you don't know where the location of the service is. It's not really that difficult.

Comment: thank you for clearing my confusion. And you can use the same WSDL at multiple level like dev/qa/prod and dont worry about changing the endpoint.

Comment: @Garry Exactly. Adding the endpoint (or rather Port) info to a WSDL is merely a convenience, not a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the end point at runtime dynamically even if it has not been defined in the WSDL. Below is the example of `javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider`. You can configure your end point in DB or configuration file thus it can be changed as per the environment.

```
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(
                BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endPoint);
```